# Add a link to display form on custom column using powershell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, column, xml, menu-item

I read several solutions that advice to use SharePoint Designer to modify the column xml definition. I would like to know if there is a way to do the same by using PowerShell.

I have a really large amount of web sites and modifying each of them once at a time using SPD is not a solution for me.

Thank you all.